# Are there any resource similar to dotnetshoutout.com & dotnetkicks.com in Java World?

Tags: java

As I'm moving from .Net to Java, please refer me the sites that contains the daily updates of java, spring, eclipse...

Comment: yep..then i push the question on the stack..:)

Answer (score 1):

[Dzone](http://www.dzone.com/) – It’s like DotNetKicks but has everything including Java stuff.

http://www.dzone.com/links/tag/java.html

Answer (score 0):

Not a daily update site, but it contains periodic podcasts from the Java world - [JavaPosse](http://www.javaposse.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Another good Java site for finding what free software is available with a short review is http://java-source.net/  I suggest you have a look if you are new to Java.  I also subscribe to http://javablogs.com/